# Boot default OS without displaying GRUB menu

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a notebook and a PC with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS installed. I've compared /etc/default/grub on both of them and the contents are identical.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

However the PC boots without displaying the GRUB menu and immediately starts the OS while the notebook doesn't. It shows the GRUB menu and a timeout of 30 seconds. Why is it so? My goal is to disable the menu on the notebook and start the OS immediately.

It also seems that the changes to that file don't have any effect.
I set

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
```

and ran `sudo update-grub` but the same menu was shown after reboot and the timeout of 30 seconds remained

I also tried to execute `sudo update-grub2` but nothing changed

I noticed that PC has **/etc/default/grub.ucf-dist** file which the notebook doesn't. The file contents are:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Not sure whether it has some influence in this case...

Below are the contents of /boot/efi on the notebook:

```
$ sudo tree /boot/efi/
[sudo] password for den: 
/boot/efi/
└── EFI
    ├── BOOT
    │   ├── BOOTX64.EFI
    │   ├── fbx64.efi
    │   └── mmx64.efi
    └── ubuntu
        ├── BOOTX64.CSV
        ├── fw
        ├── fwupx64.efi
        ├── grub.cfg
        ├── grubx64.efi
        ├── mmx64.efi
        └── shimx64.efi
```

**/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg** was changed on 21.02.2020. This must be the day on which the OS was installed.

But **/boot/grub/grub.cfg** was changed today (possibly after I had ran `update-grub`)

Comment: Did you run `update-grub` or `update-grub2` after you made those changes?

Comment: B0th r dual b00ts 0r 0nly Ubuntu?

Comment: @Yaron I didn't make any changes to that file after installation of Ubuntu on notebook.

Comment: @PRATAP Ubuntu is the only OS on both machines.

Comment: 0k..in the notebook it happened in the middle i mean after installation 0f 0S and after somedays 0r months.. 0r right from the installation afterwards??

Comment: @PRATAP It happened on notebook right after installation. But Ubuntu installation on PC has a long history. I think I installed 14.04 first then updated etc.

Comment: S0 we 0nly need to talk/discuss about notebook.. While installing Ubuntu on notebook Did you choose "something else" option.. Is there already a EFI partition 0r Y0u created a fresh EFI partition??

Comment: If you log on to notebook.. Can you see what r the contents in the EFI partition?

Comment: @PRATAP When I run lsblk I can see sda - sda1 part /boot/efi

Comment: Yes browse through file manager and see what r the contents in `/boot/efi` 0r `sudo ls /boot/efi`

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one drive and both of them has GRUB installed?